# Connect to QNX on QEMU via ssh

Tags: windows, ssh, qemu, qnx, qnx-neutrino

I would like to connect to QNX(running on the QEMU on Windows) via ssh.
Does anyone know maybe what I need to set up, configure to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903942/cannot-ssh-into-qemu-virtual-machine-running-dropbear-sshd

Comment: What is your QNX SDP version?

Comment: @I.Hamad QNX Neutrino 7.0.0